# Python: JSON string to list of dictionaries - Getting error when iterating

Tags: python, json

I am sending a JSON string from Objective-C to Python. Then I want to break contents of the string into a Python list. I am trying to iterate over a string (any string for now):

```
import json

s = '[{"i":"imap.gmail.com","p":"someP@ss"},{"i":"imap.aol.com","p":"anoterPass"}]'
jdata = json.loads(s)
for key, value in jdata.iteritems():
    print key, value
```

I get this error:

> Exception Error: 'list' object has no attribute 'iterates'

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Your JSON data is a list of dictionaries, so after `json.loads(s)` you will have `jdata` as a list, not a dictionary.

Try something like the following:

```
import json

s = '[{"i":"imap.gmail.com","p":"someP@ss"},{"i":"imap.aol.com","p":"anoterPass"}]'
jdata = json.loads(s)
for d in jdata:
    for key, value in d.iteritems():
        print key, value
```

Answer (score 5):

`json.loads(s)` will return you `list`. To iterate over it you don't need `iteritems`.

```
>>> jdata = json.loads(s)
>>> for doc in jdata:
...     for key, value in doc.iteritems():
...          print key, value
```

Comment: You `don't` need iteritems? But your solution contains it.

Answer (score 3):

for python 3.6 above, there has a little difference

```
s = '[{"i":"imap.gmail.com","p":"someP@ss"},{"i":"imap.aol.com","p":"anoterPass"}]'
jdata = json.loads(s)
print (jdata)
for d in jdata:
    for key, value in d.items():
        print (key, value)


[{'i': 'imap.gmail.com', 'p': 'someP@ss'}, {'i': 'imap.aol.com', 'p': 'anoterPass'}]
i imap.gmail.com
p someP@ss
i imap.aol.com
p anoterPass
```

Comment: It's the `.items()` call that saved me on this one; thanks