# How to parse a 'JSON string' file in Python?

Tags: python, json, file, import, io

I am working on something that is quite similar to [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13938183/python-json-string-to-list-of-dictionaries-getting-error-when-iterating).I downloaded a file which seems like to be a JSON file. But when I open it in notepad, I found that it is a very long list of dictionaries. The file essentially looks like this:

```
[
{'time':1, 'value':100},
{'time':2, 'value':105},
{'time':3, 'value':120}
]
```

I tried to load this 'JSON file' into Python like this:

```
import json
with open('data.json') as data_file:
    data = json.loads(data_file)
```

but got an error:

```
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

How can I load this file correctly into Python? I would like to iterate thru each row to extract all the 'values'. Thanks!

Comment: to use `json.loads` you need to read the file...i.e `data = json.loads(data_file.read())`

Comment: By doing this, I got the same error as that when I used `json.load()`, as suggested by @Rushy below. This file has totally 85473 rows, with the first row being `[` and last row being `]`. No quotes before and after. I think it is essentially a list object.

Answer (score 2):

Use `json.load`:

```
with open('data.json') as data_file:
    data = json.load(data_file)
```

The primary difference between `json.load` and `json.loads` is that `json.load` accepts a file (or file-like object) to read and load JSON from, whereas `json.loads` loads JSON from a string.

Comment: Thanks @Rushy. I used `json.load()` but still got an error: `ValueError: Extra data: line 371 column 2 - line 85473 column 2 (char 196700 - 43922174)`. The line 85473 is the last row. This file's first row is `[`, and the last row is `]`. There is no quotes before and after.

Comment: @user3768495 Your JSON file is most likely not valid JSON. Is there anything after the `]`?

Comment: No, nothing. The file is just like the example I showed in the question above, just with many more rows.

Comment: I just successfully read the file in R with rjson package. Just two lines: `data_file <- ("data.json")` and `data <- fromJSON(file = data_file)`. But if I do: `data <- fromJSON(paste(readLines(data_file), collapse = ""))`, it throws an error saying `incomplete final line found`. Does this information help?