# Convert list of str to dict using list comprehension

Tags: python-3.x, string, dictionary, type-conversion, list-comprehension

I have a list of strings represented as dictionaries and I want to convert them to dictionaries using list comprehension. my data looks like this:

```
['{"A":"1"}','{"B":"2"}']
```

The output should be:

```
[{"A":"1"},{"B":"2"}]
```

I tried this:

```
dict_var = [i for i in list_var]
```

And it's just returning the same result without any change!

Comment: Try `json.loads(i)` in your comprehension. Also, please don't use `list` or `dict` or other type names as variable names :-)

Comment: @JonSG That worked!!! I never do, it was only for simplifying but I have made the changes to avoid any confusion. Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: JSON string to list of dictionaries - Getting error when iterating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13938183/python-json-string-to-list-of-dictionaries-getting-error-when-iterating)

Comment: @JonSG Not really, the answer is a bit case-specific and a little long where my answer is more generic and potentially more helpful for people looking to solve the same problem. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Of course it is, `[i for i in list_var]` is just the same as `list(list_var)`!

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by using `json.loads(i)` and in a list comprehension such as:

```
dict_var = [json.loads(i) for i in list_var]
```